# Pinning Apps to dock VIA terminal or installation arguments OS Sierra

Tags: terminal, macos, dock, script

I am using meraki MDM systems manager to deploy applications for are teachers. It would save me a-lot of heart ache to be able to include a terminal command or some type of software to help with automatically pinning things to the dock, so i don't have to touch each device individually thanks in advanced!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command (replace `PATH_TO_YOUR_APP`):

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add "<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>PATH_TO_YOUR_APP</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>"
```

This adds the application to the dock. For the change to take effect, follow this up with `killall cfprefsd` and `killall Dock`.

Comment: I'm not sure how much information is needed in the `<dict>` but with the info from the answer my launcher shows up as a question mark and it doesn't work. From using the info gathered from `defaults export com.apple.dock` I was able to put the launcher back, but it contains a whole lot of info. The question is how much info is really needed to recreate a certain layout.

Comment: I've set up my dock app config [here](https://github.com/RexYuan/Blemishine/blob/main/preferences/dock.mk). Using what's dumped from `default export`.